# Feathers-mongoose $like query for MongoDb getting Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema, feathersjs

I have the following Mongoose Schema -

```
const myTableSchema = new Schema({
  Category: { type: String, required: false },
  Tag: { type: String, required: false },

  createdAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now },
});
```

Note that, both of them are String. I was trying to do a query like the following -

```
localhost:1971/api/myTable?Category[$like]=Javascript
```

I have rows with Javascript in Category column. But getting the following error-

```
{
  "name": "GeneralError",
  "message": "Can't use $like with String.",
  "code": 500,
  "className": "general-error",
  "data": {},
  "errors": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its been a while since this was discussed, but I've had a similar question and [the code provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48081784/532551) by @Daff helped me a lot, but it contains an error.

`query[field].$like` is checked for presence, but then `query[field].$search` is attached to the final query.

The correct code representation (if following the original question) should be:

```js
exports.searchRegex = function () {
  return function (hook) {
    const query = hook.params.query;
    for (let field in query) {
      if(query[field].$like && field.indexOf('$') == -1) {
        query[field] = { $regex: new RegExp(query[field].$like) }
      }
    }
    hook.params.query = query
    return hook
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB and Mongoose do not have a `$like` operator. The common way for implementing search (see [this FAQ](https://docs.feathersjs.com/faq/readme.html#how-do-i-do-search)) is adding a [hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html) that converts the searchable term into a [MongoDB $regex query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/), for example to support the `$like` syntax you are looking for:

```
exports.searchRegex = function () {
  return function (hook) {
    const query = hook.params.query;
    for (let field in query) {
      if(query[field].$like && field.indexOf('$') == -1) {
        query[field] = { $regex: new RegExp(query[field].$search) }
      }
    }
    hook.params.query = query
    return hook
  }
}
```